# How to avoid integer division warning?

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings, gfortran

In gfortran 6 there's a new warning `-Winteger-division` that is triggered when a value is truncated with integer division, as in `3/5`.

Supposing this is the intended result, is there a way to change the code such that the warning is not issued? For instance:

```
program test
integer, parameter :: n = 3, m = 5
integer, parameter :: a = n/m
end program
```

at least something less cumbersome than:

```
integer, parameter :: a = int(real(n)/real(m))
```

I would like to keep using `-Wall` (and `-Werror`), I'd rather modify the code than fiddle with the compiler options for specific files, with specific compiler versions, etc.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That's a simplified example. The problem code has longer computations with parameters defined in other files, dependent on preprocessor definitions, but which still require integer division where the truncation is intended.

Comment: i do not have this version of gfortran to play with, but that is really unacceptable if perfectly valid code generates warnings by default.  Is it smart enough to not bother you in case of exact integer result ( eg. `n*(n+1)/2` ?

Comment: @agentp It's not by default, it's with `-Wall`, which gives warnings for many other pieces of valid code (implicit conversions, unused variables, etc.). What I don't like is that there seems to be no reasonable and compact way of writing the code to avoid the warning (I wouldn't call `a=int(real(n)/m)` "reasonable). But yes, the warning disappears if `n=10`, for instance. I wonder why it doesn't give a warning for just "possibly truncated" (i.e., not constant) results: if a (maybe intentional) truncated result deserves a warning, surely a possibly truncated result deserves it too.

Comment: If it helps, the `int(...)` part isn't necessary: it happens implicitly.

Comment: @francescalus None of it is necessary, but without the `int(...)` you get a "change of value in conversion" warning/error

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with the implied warnings by `-Wall`.

Comment: If a preprocessor is already in use, is it an option to define something like "#define _div_(p,q) = int(real(p)/real(q))" and use this macro in a parameter statement (say, "integer, parameter :: a = _div_(m,n)")? If such integer division appears a lot in a particular file and -Wno-... is not desired, it might be (potentially) useful as a workaround.

Comment: @Jellby: As to why it only works for constants: Because it's evaluated at compile time. For non-constants, it would have to generate a warning for ALL integer divisons, or alternatively insert code to check at runtime whether the result is truncated. Both of these options tend to generate a *lot* of noise for real programs, and the second one additionally comes at a performance cost as well. Think: something that is heuristically useful, not something that comes out of some beautiful Grand Unified Theory of compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You can [turn off specific warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Error-and-Warning-Options.html#Error-and-Warning-Options) using the form `-Wno-[warningname]`. Any warnings that are not specifically negated are still reported. For your case, you can use:

```
-Wall -Wno-integer-division
```

**Edit:** Note that `-Wall` is not used by all compilers (for instance, ifort). That said, if you use `-Wall`, and want to avoid using `-Wno-integer-division`, then I'm unaware of any way to prevent the integer division warnings without using  `real` and `int` to make the proper conversions.

However, as you would rather not use a compiler option, and find the extra type-conversions cumbersome, then as long as you can live without `a` being a `parameter` (that is, just a normal `integer`) you could write a procedure that does all the explicit conversions for you. For example:

```
module utility_fcns
    implicit none
contains
    integer function intdiv(i1, i2) result(this)
        integer, intent(in) :: i1, i2
        this = int( real(i1) / real(i2) )
    end function intdiv
end module utility_fcns
```

```
program test
    use utility_fcns, only: intdiv
    implicit none

    integer :: a
    integer, parameter :: n = 3, m = 5

    a = intdiv(n,m)
    print *, a
end program test
```

So, using `intdiv(n,m)` is a bit less typing, but the result is not a parameter...

If that is a deal-breaker, then consider passing `a` to a subroutine with `intent(in)`. Then any attempt to change its value issues an error, so you get the same behavior.

Comment: @Jellby Ah, I see now. I made an edit, with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for trying, it doesn't help when `a` is used for dimensioning a static array, though. Working with a codebase dating from Fortran77 times, I want to keep changes to a minimum. On the good side: it catched a bug (`m+3/2` instead of `(m+3)/2`).

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. I know that refactoring F77 code can be a trial and probably not worth the effort just to avoid these warning messages. That said, although it would require some changes, if you take the suggestion to pass some variable such as `a` to a *subroutine*, then it can be used to specify array dimensions (not sure if that's what you meant).

Comment: The arrays may be in common blocks (sigh!). But really, if I have to create new procedures and change the arguments of existing ones, I'd rather write `a=int(real(m)/n)` ;)